# spring boot - IOException: Alias name [keycert] does not identify a key entry #13

Tags: java, spring-boot, https, keystore, pem

I'm using the following library on a Spring Boot application for activating HTTPS through `pem` files:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.dentrassi.crypto</groupId>
  <artifactId>pem-keystore</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's my code:

**application.properties**

```
# SSL
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/keystore.properties
server.ssl.key-store-type=PEMCFG
server.ssl.key-store-password=dummy
server.ssl.key-alias=keycert
```

**keystore/keystore.properties**

```
alias=keycert
source.key=src/main/resources/keystore/private-key.pem
source.cert=src/main/resources/keystore/certificate.pem
```

**Main class: AnecdoticApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AnecdoticApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException {
        Security.addProvider(new de.dentrassi.crypto.pem.PemKeyStoreProvider());
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PEM");
        SpringApplication.run(AnecdoticApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But this is generating following error at deploying the app and this is shutting down the app automatically:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.toxi.alexa.AnecdoticApplication.main(AnecdoticApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:238) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1077) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [keycert] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:234) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1074) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [keycert] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:337) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

The error is: **java.io.IOException: Alias name [keycert] does not identify a key entry**

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keystore may constains few keys. PEM type is cerificate and private key format. You can not use it as keystore.

You should create your keystore and add your certificate to them:

```
keytool -import -alias keycert -file certificate.pem -keystore keystore.p12 -storepass password
```

Let change:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
```

and use in configuration

```
# SSL
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=path/to/your/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=keycert
```